# Android Network/WIFI Location worldwide

Tags: android, location

Is the Android Network/Wifi Location in all countries available?

I am especially interested in China, most European Countrys (Germany, France, GB, Spain, ...) and of course the United States and Canada.

Comment: worldwide, no. i am confident it doesn't work in antartica or in the middle of the pacific ocean.

Comment: it's work if you are connect to gsm network or by wifi

Comment: You're right I think ;) Maybe I asked wrong. @njzk2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that location isn't relation with which country or are you reffer about street view?.

I hadn't problems to use my apps in China (it use geo location and maps) i had problems when i wanted to use street view ...

Comment: No StreetView, I'am only interested in Coordinates gathered via LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
So, for this I think, every Mobile Phone Base Station must send out its own Coordinates. My Question will be clearer I think, if I ask if this is an International Standard